# How to get EXE directory from installshield?

Tags: installation, installshield

I am so newbie with `installshield`

How to get EXE directory from installshield ?

**This is I tried so far ..**

```
SETUPEXEDIR
```

> Error: symbol "SETUPEXEDIR" not found.

```
SRCDIR
```

> C:...\AppData\Local\Temp...

```
SUPPORTDIR
```

> C:

```
WINSYSDIR
```

> Error: symbol "WINSYSDIR" not found.

```
TARGETDIR
```

> Error: symbol "TARGETDIR" not found.

```
WINDIR
```

> ""

```
WindowsVolume
```

> Error: symbol "WindowsVolume" not found.

```
SOURCEDIR
```

> Error: symbol "SOURCEDIR" not found.

I am working on installshield professional version 6.31

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I am building a single setup.exe, it doesn't .msi file to launch setup.

Answer (score 0):

how exactly are you retrieving these properties ?
SETUPEXEDIR should work, but you have to obtain it properly like this:

```
MsiGetProperty( hMSI, "SETUPEXEDIR", Value, Size );
```

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpIScriptWIProperty.htm

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a InstallScript project? You should specify that.

I think your searching for PACKAGE_LOCATION system variable.

SRCDIR is related to a Windows Installer property and not available in InstallScript projects, says the documentation. But SCRDIR is a filled variable in the setup.ilg file.

You have also to understand that the single self-extracting executable file package isn't the setup.exe that is executing your InstallScript. The self-extracting executable package get's extracted to a temp folder and the setup.exe will be started. It's not possible to customize this with an InstallScript.